# How to move the remaining columns to the next page in PHP

Tags: php, html

Hi everyone I 've been searching on the net but nothing comes to rescue.I have the code that generates the table.The problem I have is that the code display all the columns in one page and I want it to display only 10 columns and the remaining columns to the next page and also if the columns are still more than 10 ,display only 10 and take the remaining to the next page.Here is what 
I did so far. My output is as follows

reg  |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34

I need something like

reg  |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10

reg  |11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20

reg  |21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30

reg  |31|32|33|34

HERE IS MY CODE.

```
   foreach($trips as $key => $element){
   $out .= "<tr>";

    $out .= "<td>$key</td>";
    foreach($element as $subkey => $subelement){

    $out .= "<td >$subelement</td>"; 

    } } $out .= "</tr>";

    }
    $out .= "</table>";
    print $out;
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you have any attempt to limit the thing?

Comment: If array data is coming from database then you can use pagination

Comment: Try some manipulations with `LIMIT 10 OFFSET ###` in your sql query. It's called pagination.

Comment: The Data is from an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Finally found the solution to break that down using only php

```
$tripIds = array_unique($tripIds);
$tripChunks = array_chunk($tripIds,$parameterChunk);

foreach($tripChunks as $tripChunk):

$out = ""; $out .= "<table>";

// td padding for station name
$out .= "<td style='width:123px;padding:0px 15.5px 0px 9.8px;border: 10px solid transparent;     color:red;background-color: #DBDBDB;page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;'></td>";


foreach ($tripIds as $keys=>$value):

if(!in_array($value, $tripChunk)) continue;

$out .= "<td style='width:123px;padding:0px 15.5px 0px 9.8px;border: 10px solid transparent; color:red;background-color: #DBDBDB;page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;'>$value</td>";
$counter++;

 endforeach;
 $i=0;

foreach ($newArray as $keys=>$value):

$out_temp = "<tr>";

$out_temp .= "<td style='padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;'>$keys</td>";
 foreach ($value as $index=>$valu2):

 if(!in_array($index, $tripChunk))
    continue;
 else
 {
    $out .= $out_temp;
    $out_temp = ""; 
 }

 $out .= "<td style='padding:0px 4px 0px 5px;page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-  after:auto;'>$valu2</td>";
 endforeach;

 $out .= "</tr>";
 endforeach;


  $out .= "</table>";
   print $out;

   endforeach; //tripchunk
```